# How to avoid overriding attributes of system libraries in Python?

Tags: python, python-module

Say we have a buggy piece of code that accidentally overrides an attribute of some system library, like this:

```
import socket
socket.error = 'some other object'
```

Is there any way to prevent this behavior, or to find the code responsible for doing that?

I tried making a property out of socket.error, but that did not work:

```
def fget(self):
    return socket.error

def fset(self, value):
    raise SystemError('You cannot alter this attribute.')

# From now on, settings socket.error = x should raise an error
socket.error = property(fget, fset)
```

Comment: Can you just grep for the naughty line? `$ grep -r 'socket.error =' *`

Comment: Really, this happens so rarely in production code. You'll figure it out quickly enough when it does happen and grep is your friend.

Comment: grep didn't find anything. The naughty line is probably something like `import socket as sock; x = 'error'; setattr(sock, x, 'some other object')`

Comment: Then use binary search. Disable half your code, see if `error` is being set. If not, switch what is disabled. If so, focus on that half and disable half of it again. Wash, rince, repeat.

Comment: As a side note, the reason your attempt didn't work is that `property` creates descriptors, which only work in classes, not in modules. (That's oversimplifying a bit to the point of almost lying… but without explaining how attribute lookup works in new-style class instances, I don't know a better way to put it. If you want the real explanation, read [Customizing attribute access](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access), especially 3.4.2.3.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could (temporarily) stick this in your code:

```
class Bridge(object):
    def __init__(self, module):
        self.__dict__['module'] = module
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.module, attr)
    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        raise TypeError('{a!r} can not be set'.format(a=attr))

import sys
import socket
socket = sys.modules['socket'] = Bridge(socket)
```

Then setting attributes on `socket` (at least in the most usual ways) would raise an exception. The traceback will allow you to locate the error.

```
print(socket.error)
setattr(socket, 'error', 'blah')
```

yields

```
% test.py
<class 'socket.error'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    setattr(socket, 'error', 'blah')
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 10, in __setattr__
    raise TypeError('{a!r} can not be set'.format(a=attr))
TypeError: 'error' can not be set
```

Comment: This won't work, because if you run `import socket` from another filename the system library will be seen, instead of the created bridge.

Comment: @delnan - that is correct, but sys.modules will not contain a reference to the Bridge instance, but a reference to the system library. The actual reference to the Bridge instance will only be visible from where you defined it. Perhaps also stick it into sys.modules?

Comment: @MihneaGiurgea: Good point. Setting `sys.modules['socket'] = Bridge(socket)` will fix that.